# Images Duplicate inside Switch Case statement

Tags: jquery, json, web-services, switch-statement

In here my EventType in the Database is integer type.here it return,

EventTypes are 1,2,3

I need to separate EventType 1 , EventTtpe 2 & EventType 3(to Separate div's)
Here i paste the Ajax Success message.In here it Duplicates.That's means i use EventType 2 & EventType 3 for the separate div's but it shows event type 2 duplicated images.it doesn't show EventType 3 images

```
     success: function (msg) {
                $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"clsMainDiv\">"); 
$.each(msg.d, function (index, item) {
                        imageUrl = item.ImagePath == "" ? "./images/defaultPicture.png" : (item.EventFolderName + '/' + item.ImagePath);
                    evntnme= item.EventName.length > 10 ? (item.EventName.substring(0, 10) + '...') : item.EventName;
                    EventType = item.EventType;
                    alert(EventType);
                    switch(EventType){ // event type returns 1,2,3

                     case 2: <-- Here i use to list EventType 2 images

                         $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"PEvents\">")
                         $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"clsInnerDiv\"><span>" + evntnme+ "</span><img src=\"" + imageUrl + "\" onclick=\"OpenEvent(" + item.ID + ")\" /></div>");
                         $("#LoadEvents").append("</div>");
                     case 3: <-- here i use to list event type 3 images

                        $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"HEvents\">")
                        $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"clsInnerDiv\"><span>" + evntnme+ "</span><img src=\"" + imageUrl + "\" onclick=\"OpenEvent(" + item.ID + ")\" /></div>");
                        $("#LoadEvents").append("</div>");

                }
                });
                $("#LoadEvents").append("</div>");
               },
                //Some code here
```

Comment: You are missing break; after cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look how switch statements syntax works:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

In your code example, if `case 2` is true, it runs through case 2 but since there is no break it does not stop there and additionally runs through case 3. To prevent that from happening, use `break;`s after cases:

```
switch(EventType){ // event type returns 1,2,3

     case 2: <-- Here i use to list EventType 2 images

         $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"PEvents\">")
         $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"clsInnerDiv\"><span>" + evntnme+ "</span><img src=\"" + imageUrl + "\" onclick=\"OpenEvent(" + item.ID + ")\" /></div>");
         $("#LoadEvents").append("</div>");
         break;
     case 3: <-- here i use to list event type 3 images

        $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"HEvents\">")
        $("#LoadEvents").append("<div class=\"clsInnerDiv\"><span>" + evntnme+ "</span><img src=\"" + imageUrl + "\" onclick=\"OpenEvent(" + item.ID + ")\" /></div>");
        $("#LoadEvents").append("</div>");
        break;

}
```